# "Connection reset" by keycloak's Java adapter

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm noticing a bunch of "***java.net.SocketException: Connection reset***" (not "*Connection reset by peer*") exceptions in an application which uses Keycloak's adapter (Version 2.1.0-Final). The AdapterConfig object in the provider (which is then used to build the Http connection pool) looks something like this:

```
{
    "realm": "realm_name",
    "realm-public-key": "xxxxx",
    "auth-server-url": "some_url_going_through_AWS_ALB",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "client_id",
    "public-client": true,
    "principal-attribute": "email"
}
```

It's worth mentioning that the auth-server-url points to a publicly available HTTPS URL served through an ALB (AWS's Application Load Balancer) and to a NAT gateway in front of an EC2 node residing in a private subnet. Moreover, the exception is logged along with a message from the adapter. For example: "*failed to turn code into token*" in "*OAuthRequestAuthenticator*" Or "Refresh token failure" in "*RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext*".

This problem is not consistently reproducible, which leads me to believe that the connection pool drops some connections (perhaps the idle ones) without replacing them properly. Is there a way in the adapter (or its configuration) to enforce retires or connection replacements in the pool (similar to what database connection pools offer)? I don't mind updating the adapter if it help.

Comment: I may have found the problem, which has nothing to do with keycloak's adapter. AWS's NAT Gateway terminates timed out connections with RST packet (as opposed to FIN packet) leaving the connections in the pool in a bad state. One suggestion out there is to use NAT Instance which terminates connections with FIN packet. This isn't an option for us. So I'll have to figure out a way to keep 'em alive using a heartbeat. Because we can't directly manage the pool maintained by the adapter and perhaps replace faulty connections.

Comment: Can I ask why the NAT is in the incoming network path? 
In order words why not allow the ALB to route directly to either the keycloak instances in your private subnets or a reverse proxy in front of them?

Comment: NAT is for outgoing connections from a service living in a private subnet in which we use Keycloak's adapter in order to connect to a publicly available keycloak server.

Comment: That makes sense.